# Updating child Components with state change in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I know  this question has been asked a couple of times and the general concession is that props cant be changed when it has already passed down to a child. The situation I have here is that basically i have a different onClick function in a different file that updates the the  id="movie-header" with an innerHTML, the DOMSubtreeModified and componentDidUpdatedetects the change and pass down the new props to Child "Ebay".

So the question here is how do I get the Ebay component to update its state and make use of the new value with every change to the  state in the moviemodalwindow(the parent of the Ebay)

MovieModalWindow.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../MovieGo.css";
import Ebay from "../Store/Ebay";

class MovieModalWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 1
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var element = document.getElementById("movie-header");
    element.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", this.myFunction(element));
    var name = this.state.name + 1;
    this.setState({ name: [...this.state.name, name] });
  }

  myFunction = input => event => {
    this.setState({ name: input.innerHTML });
  };
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.name != this.state.name) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("keyword", this.state.name);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span onClick={onClose} class="close">
            &times;
          </span>
          <h1 id="movie-header" />
          <div className="middle-window">
            <div className="left">
              <Ebay id="ebay" keyword={this.state.name} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3>PLOT</h3>
          <p id="moviedetails" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieModalWindow;
```

Ebay.js File

```
import React from "react"

class Ebay extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      data:[],
    }
  }
  componentWillUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if (prevProps.keywords!=this.props.keywords){
      console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("keyword"))
    }

  render(){
    const{newInput} =this.props
    return(
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Ebay
```

Comment: You want ``Ebay``'s state to update when props of it change?  Does your `console.log` get hit?  (also you're missing a closing bracket on `componentWillUpdate`)

Comment: Yes but only once

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if I'm answering the question you're asking, so apologies if this isn't what you're asking.

Step 1.  Make Ebay's prop's change when you need this update to happen.  (I think you stated you already have this occurring?)

Step 2:  Make Ebay's state update when the props change.  Here you can just watch for prop changes with `componentWillReceiveProps` and update the state accordingly.

```
class Ebay extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.keyword !== this.props.keyword) {
       this.setState({ data: ['something new'] });
    }
  }

  render() { ... }
}
```